# firebase class export method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have seen many people create a firebase class and export it with two different ways, `export default firebase` and `export default new firebase()` . Can someone explain the difference?

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import config from "./firebaseConfig";

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
  }
}
 
export default Firebase;
```

and

```
import app from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firebase-firestore";

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
    this.db = app.firestore();
  }
}

export default new Firebase();
```

Comment: It would help if you edit the question to show the code that actually defines `firebase`.  Is it an import?  Where did it come from?

Answer (score 1):

It is the same. The first one is shorter and hence used more widely. You can use whichever you like

Answer (score 0):

The first one returns a class reference to you Firebase class.  The module that imports this will have to create their own new instance of it using `new Firebase()`.

The second one returns a new instance of that Firebase class.  All modules that imports this will get the same single instance of the Firebase class - it is effectively a singleton shared throughout the project.

Comment: witch one do you suggest?

Comment: Which one meets your needs or preferences better?